# Laravel pass the list of url to correct id

Tags: php, laravel

i'm trying to pass the correct URL for specific list with id i'm not sure if you get what i mean but i will show an example:
code something like where->subject_id->is->equal->level_id

**Example**: Level1 has sections A,B
             Level2 has sections A,B

**Note:** **Parent=Level then Child=Section**

**Controller:**

```
public function getlevel()
{

    $levels=Level::all();

    return view('lists.getlevel',compact('levels'));

}

public function getsection($id) 
{

   $sections=Section::findorFail($id)->where('Level_id', '=', $id)->get();
   $level = Level::find(1);

   return view('lists.getsection',compact('sections'));

}
```

**getlevel.blade**:

```
@foreach($levels as $level)
<a href="what to write?">{{ $level->levelname }}
@endforeach
```

**`Route:`**

```
Route::get('lists', 'ListController@getlevel');
Route::get('lists/{id}', 'ListController@getsection');
```

Comment: So what is your question ??

Comment: i cannot push the link to the right id when i click level it wont go to the section where it suppose to be

Answer (score 0):

In laravel findOrFail is a where on your model primary key:

```
Section::findOrFail(9);
```

generate a sql like:

```
select * from sections where id = 9;
```

You should change your query to something like this:

```
$sections=Section::where('id', $id)->where('Level_id', '=', 'id')->get();
```

or if you want first one:

```
$sections=Section::where('id', $id)->where('Level_id', '=', 'id')->first();
```

Comment: on my URL what to write?

Comment: The id of your section.